# Click events propagating to hidden SVG images with pointer-events="visible" in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

It appears like the "visible" value for the SVG object property "pointer-events" is not being respected in the newer versions of Firefox (confirmed for v34 and v35).

I have images with the following definitions embedded in an SVG:

`<image x="10" y="10" id="svg-image1" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />`

`<image x="10" y="210" id="svg-image2" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" pointer-events="visible" visibility="hidden" />`

The second doesn't show up as visible in the SVG when painted but when the area the second image occupies is clicked click events are being fired. I've confirmed that Chrome has the expected behavior where the click events on the hidden element are not fired if pointer-events is set to "visible" but click events are fired for the first image.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9uqo33j/ you can reproduce by clicking below the visible image in Firefox.

Any idea why this is or how to get the expected behavior out of Firefox? It is respecting pointer-events="none" but there are many places where I potentially toggle visibility and I would rather not depend on remembering to reset pointer-events or the mouse handler every time I toggle the image visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them display="none" till I get the [bug fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119698).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is actually a regression in Firefox:

[D3 events firing on a hidden svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844884/d3-events-firing-on-a-hidden-svg-element)

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119698